# Grinding while going into gear

Tags: manual-transmission

Ok need help figuring this out before I take it to 50 different places giving me different diognosis. So when I shift into first and second it grinds going into gear but as soon as I have it into gear it’s good. Sometimes it don’t even make the noise of grinding into gear but 80% of the time it does. I can also not go into 6th gear and for 5th gear it sometimes slips out of gear and I have to throw it back into gear. Dealership told me it might be my tranny, but I feel it’s a clutch issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the year/make/model/engine of the vehicle in question? I think, from your description, you have two issues: clutch & transmission. The grinding is indicative of the clutch dragging (not disengaging completely). The 5th/6th gear not staying is pretty often an internal transmission issue.

Comment: I would suggest that it is the first / second synchro that could be weak - but does depend on the noise... Then the 5th / 6th issue could be the se3lector detent springs have failed... Both mean transmission remove & strip down...

Comment: an input bearing/bushing can also cause gear shifting problem check it before going through a tear down of the tranny

Comment: Failing master/slave cylinder will also cause most of these issues, and it's (usually, depending on the car) the cheapest and easiest fix.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple causes for this condition, but here is a simple one to check:
The transmission oil seems to be too thick, or too cold. Many people experiencing the grinding shift solved it with replacing the oil with synthetic oil, which doesn't oppose flow at cold or warm temperatures.  Try this simple test.
On a cold morning, start your engine with your clutch depressed.  If you release the clutch and notice that the engine RPM's dip, that's a sign that the transmission oil actually opposes mechanical rotation because it's thick and cold.